# Wordpress The theme directory "a191f36de8a8e87d91a0a36d98a869cab74cc49f~default" does not exist

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am having a website dawrkawn.com but when i try to crustimize the theme from dashboard i am getting this error. im using a wordpess, kindly help

The theme directory "a191f36de8a8e87d91a0a36d98a869cab74cc49f~default" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the permision of folder with theme. For example set it to 777 (temporarily). Also reload the permalinks.

Comment: Name of this folder is odd for me. Mayby there is a problem?
You try to disable all plugins ye?

Comment: this is a fresh install, changing the file permission still dont helps

Comment: For sure you reload the permalinks?